# What's the equivalent of PHP's " .= " in Javascript, to add something to a variable..?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

In PHP you can do:

```
$myvar = "Hello";
$myvar .= " world!";
echo $myvar;
```

The output is: Hello world!

How can I do this in Javascript/jQuery..?

Comment: I guess: strOut = strOut + "whatever"; is the way to go..?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var a = 'Hello';
    a += ' world';
alert(a);
```

You'll get a dialog with "Hello world".

Be careful with this, though:

```
var a = 3;
    a += 'foo';
```

Result: **3foo**. But:

```
var a = 3;
    a += 4;
    a += 'b';
```

You'll get an interesting result, and probably not the one you expect.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the danger inherent in the overloaded `+` operator

Answer (score 4):

The PHP concatenation operator is `.`

The Javascript concatenation operator is `+`

So you're looking for `+=`

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript the string concatenation operation is `+` and the compound string concatenation and assignment operator is `+=`. Thus:

```
var myvar = "Hello";
myvar += " world!";
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it.

I was doing this:

```
var myvar = "Hello";
var myvar += " world!";
var myvar += " again!";
```

I guess the multiple var was my problem...

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

`+` is the String concatenation operator in Javascript.  PHP and Javascript, both being loosely-typed languages, deal with conflicts between *addition* and *concatentation* in different ways.  PHP deals with it by having a completely separate operator (as you stated, `.`).  Javascript deals with it by having certain rules for which operation is being performed.  For that reason, you need to be aware of whether your variable is *typed* as a String or a Number.

Example:

- `"1" + "3"`: In PHP, this equals the number 4.  In JavaScript, this equals "13".
  To get the desired `4` in Javascript, you would do `Number("1") + Number("3")`.

The basic idea in Javascript is that any two variables that are both *typed* as Numbers with a `+` operator in between will be added.  If either is a string, they will be concatenated.

Answer (score 0):

var a="Hello";
a+="world !";

output: Hello world!